# using charts_flutter in flutter program

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new to flutter and dart, and I need to use the charts_flutter (https://pub.dev/packages/charts_flutter package), however, the code their example code doesn't natively work. There are parameters required, or other processes, which I'm not sure what to do with. The code I'm using is the most basic line graph example, found here https://google.github.io/charts/flutter/example/time_series_charts/simple I would really appreciate if someone could help me make this work because I don't see any main function to run like what im used to, thanks so much.

Comment: The /example/ folder inside charts_flutter in the GitHub repo contains a full Flutter app with many demo examples. The main function is here: https://github.com/google/charts/blob/master/charts_flutter/example/lib/main.dart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SimpleTimeSeriesChart.withSampleData() directly, see code snippet below 
You can copy paste run full code below 
code snippet

```
    children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(flex: 5, child: SimpleTimeSeriesChart.withSampleData()),
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
          ],
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:charts_flutter/flutter.dart' as charts;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SimpleTimeSeriesChart extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<charts.Series> seriesList;
  final bool animate;

  SimpleTimeSeriesChart(this.seriesList, {this.animate});

  /// Creates a [TimeSeriesChart] with sample data and no transition.
  factory SimpleTimeSeriesChart.withSampleData() {
    return new SimpleTimeSeriesChart(
      _createSampleData(),
      // Disable animations for image tests.
      animate: false,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new charts.TimeSeriesChart(
      seriesList,
      animate: animate,
      // Optionally pass in a [DateTimeFactory] used by the chart. The factory
      // should create the same type of [DateTime] as the data provided. If none
      // specified, the default creates local date time.
      dateTimeFactory: const charts.LocalDateTimeFactory(),
    );
  }

  /// Create one series with sample hard coded data.
  static List<charts.Series<TimeSeriesSales, DateTime>> _createSampleData() {
    final data = [
      new TimeSeriesSales(new DateTime(2017, 9, 19), 5),
      new TimeSeriesSales(new DateTime(2017, 9, 26), 25),
      new TimeSeriesSales(new DateTime(2017, 10, 3), 100),
      new TimeSeriesSales(new DateTime(2017, 10, 10), 75),
    ];

    return [
      new charts.Series<TimeSeriesSales, DateTime>(
        id: 'Sales',
        colorFn: (_, __) => charts.MaterialPalette.blue.shadeDefault,
        domainFn: (TimeSeriesSales sales, _) => sales.time,
        measureFn: (TimeSeriesSales sales, _) => sales.sales,
        data: data,
      )
    ];
  }
}

/// Sample time series data type.
class TimeSeriesSales {
  final DateTime time;
  final int sales;

  TimeSeriesSales(this.time, this.sales);
}

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the home page of your application. It is stateful, meaning
  // that it has a State object (defined below) that contains fields that affect
  // how it looks.

  // This class is the configuration for the state. It holds the values (in this
  // case the title) provided by the parent (in this case the App widget) and
  // used by the build method of the State. Fields in a Widget subclass are
  // always marked "final".

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      // This call to setState tells the Flutter framework that something has
      // changed in this State, which causes it to rerun the build method below
      // so that the display can reflect the updated values. If we changed
      // _counter without calling setState(), then the build method would not be
      // called again, and so nothing would appear to happen.
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // This method is rerun every time setState is called, for instance as done
    // by the _incrementCounter method above.
    //
    // The Flutter framework has been optimized to make rerunning build methods
    // fast, so that you can just rebuild anything that needs updating rather
    // than having to individually change instances of widgets.
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        // Center is a layout widget. It takes a single child and positions it
        // in the middle of the parent.
        child: Column(
          // Column is also a layout widget. It takes a list of children and
          // arranges them vertically. By default, it sizes itself to fit its
          // children horizontally, and tries to be as tall as its parent.
          //
          // Invoke "debug painting" (press "p" in the console, choose the
          // "Toggle Debug Paint" action from the Flutter Inspector in Android
          // Studio, or the "Toggle Debug Paint" command in Visual Studio Code)
          // to see the wireframe for each widget.
          //
          // Column has various properties to control how it sizes itself and
          // how it positions its children. Here we use mainAxisAlignment to
          // center the children vertically; the main axis here is the vertical
          // axis because Columns are vertical (the cross axis would be
          // horizontal).
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(flex: 5, child: SimpleTimeSeriesChart.withSampleData()),
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```